# Почему после присвоения значения в свойство "Capasity" его значение не меняется?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

```
class ArrList
{
    object[] array = Array.Empty<object>();
    private int count;//кол-во элементов
    private int capasity;//размерность
    public ArrList() { }
    public int Capasity
    {
        get { return array.Length; }// свойство 2
        set
        {
            if (value < count) throw new Exception("Value less than array length");

            if (capasity != array.Length)
            {
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    object[] temp = new object[value];
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++)
                        {
                            temp[i] = array[i];
                        }
                    }
                    array = temp;
                    capasity = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

в картинке 1,присваиваю новое значение s.Capasity=12

в картинке 2 ничего не меняется, хотя в поле "Capasity" доб-ся новое значение

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGR6I.png)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHbL6.png

в свойстве "Capasity" написал capasity = value,но все равно ничего не меняется.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Удалите из своего кода лишние пустые строки. Невозможно читать его в таком виде!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,убрал

Comment: `if (capasity != array.Length)` -> `if (value != array.Length)`

Comment: Поле `private int capasity;` вообще не нужно. Избавьтесь от него.

Comment: @ ExplodingKitten, спасибо!!!!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, раньше StackOverFlow вылетал из-за отсутствия переменной